# Why are the in and out angles different in my bended edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
  \tikz \graph [nodes={empty nodes, fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, draw}]{
      \foreach \i in {1,...,5} { a --[bend left={2*90/5-(\i-1)*90/5}] b; }
    };
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

The result looks quite elegant, but I actually want the `in` and `out` angle of the edges to be equal. It now seems that `in=180` for all edges, although the description for `/tikz/bend left=<angle>` in the PGF manual states

> This option sets `out=<angle>,in=180-<angle>,relative`. If no `<angle>`
> is given, the last given `bend left` or `bend right` angle is used.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe relevant http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48590/124842

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how `bend left` is defined

> ```
> \tikzoption{bend left}[]{%
>   \def\pgf@temp{#1}%
>   \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty%
>   \else%
>     \def\tikz@to@bend{#1}%
>   \fi%
>   \let\tikz@to@out=\tikz@to@bend%
>   \c@pgf@counta=180\relax%
>   \advance\c@pgf@counta by-\tikz@to@out\relax%
>   \edef\tikz@to@in{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
>   \tikz@to@switch@on%
>   \tikz@to@relativetrue%
> }
> ```

As you can see, Ti*k*Z uses TeX's arithmetics to calculated the `in` factor. Therefore you cannot pass a mathematical expression to it.

Instead, you should do the arithmetics yourself, such as the following

```
  \tikz \graph [nodes={empty nodes, fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, draw}]{
      \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
          a --[
              /utils/exec={\pgfmathsetmacro\bendangle{2*90/5-(\i-1)*90/5}},
              bend left=\bendangle
          ] b; }
    };
```

[image]

## Update

@Ignasi suggests the following

```
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \bendangle using {2*90/5-(\i-1)*90/5}] in {1,...,5}
    { a--[bend left=\bendangle] b;}
```

And then I found the following works

```
\foreach \i [evaluate={\bendangle=2*90/5-(\i-1)*90/5;}] in {1,...,5}
    { a--[bend left=\bendangle] b;}
```

If you have `\usetikzlibrary{math}`, then the following also works

```
  \foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
      a --[
          evaluate={\bendangle=2*90/5-(\i-1)*90/5;},
          bend left=\bendangle
      ] b; }
```

---

For the first case, the key is handled by `/pgf/foreach/evaluate` and then `\pgffor@assign@@parse@old`.

For the second case, the key is handled by `/pgf/foreach/evaluate` and then `\pgffor@assign@@parse`.

For the third case, the key is handled by `/tikz/evaluate` and then `\tikz@math`.

Comment: or `\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \bendangle using {2*90/5-(\i-1)*90/5}] in {1,...,5}{ a--[bend left=\bendangle] b;}`

Comment: @Ignasi Interesting! I found `evaluate={\bendangle=2*90/5-(\i-1)*90/5;}` also works, and is compatible with `\tikzmath`.